# NengoDL installation issue with nengo version 4

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I try to run code for spiking neural network, the model convert CNN to spiking using following code:

```
import nengo
import nengo_dl

import tensorflow as tf
#print(cnn_model1.summary())

sfr = 20
converter = nengo_dl.Converter(
    funcmodel,
    swap_activations={
        tf.keras.activations.relu: nengo.SpikingRectifiedLinear()},
    scale_firing_rates=sfr,
    synapse=0.005,
    inference_only=False)
```

But I got error message as in below

```
UserWarning: This version of NengoDL has not been tested with your Nengo version (4.0.0). The latest fully supported version is 3.2.0.
      warnings.warn(warnstr)
```

and

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'
```

Then try to install nengo older version using this code

```
pip install  nengo==3.2.0 nengo-dl==3.4.0 nengo-gui==0.4.7
```

and same error appears

Can any one help me to fix this error